# how to digitally sign xml string in android

Tags: android, digital-signature

Hi all i have xml string that I should send along with HttpRequest to the URL. Before sending it to the server,I need to digitally sign the xml string with password for security purpose.
I want to know how to implement this in android. To do xml digital signing,we need following libraries: javax.xml.crypto,javax.xml.crypto.dsig,javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo,javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec,javax.xml.crypto.dom,javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom
But unfortunately this libraries are not supported by android.
Is there any other way to digitally sign xml string in android.
Plz note I am to do it from java but not in android.
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you got success?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question.

Android has those Java Crypto libraries since api level one.

http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/package-summary.html

Here is an example using it:

http://www.developer.com/ws/android/encrypting-with-android-cryptography-api.html

Comment: Is this about XMLDSig? Just crypto is not enough for XML signing.

Comment: Yes its about xml signing with .p12 certificate having keystore and its password

Comment: Stephan I tried to do it all the possible way that I can think but still its not working for me

Comment: Basically it required 2jar bouncycastle provider and xmlsecUrity which are throwing exeption while running the app